# mongodb - modeling 2 documents with relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am modeling my documents and have a problem now:

In my app the users have a list of offers, which they can accept. So I have two documents, "users" and "offers". I want to show my users, which offers they have accepted at which time. But partners (people, who insert offers) should see which user accepts which offer at what time as well.

My first thought was to work with embedded data in both documents:

**Users:**

```
 offers: {
    accepted: [{
      offer: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Offer'
      },
      time: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    }]
  }
```

**Offers:**

```
 costumer: {
    accepted: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        time: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    }]
 }
```

Pro:
Easy to query

Con:
Duplicated data

-

My other though was to create a new document for that:

**AcceptedOffers:**

```
offer: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Offer'
      },
user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
time: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
```

Which solution would be better, or maybe, is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding the data in both documents would be my advice.

In MongoDB, the data schema should be based on the requirements of the application. Duplicated data is not as serious a concern as in relational databases. In this case, the User document is designed to accommodate the application for users and the Offer document is designed to accommodate the application for partners.